# Unable to fetch data from json file in multiple object case

Tags: html, api, rest

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <body>
    <h1>show me btc current rate</h1>
    <p>
      current btc rate: <span id="btc_rate"></span><br />   
    </p>
    <script>
      const api_url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json';
  async function getBTC()
  {
        const response = await fetch(api_url);
        const data = await response.json();
        const {rate} = data;
        document.getElementById('btc_rate').textContent = rate;     
 }
getBTC();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> I was trying to fetch bitcoin current rate from
> https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json but somehow it
> is not working.

Here is the json file :

```html
{
"time": {
"updated": "Aug 8, 2020 13:10:00 UTC",
"updatedISO": "2020-08-08T13:10:00+00:00",
"updateduk": "Aug 8, 2020 at 14:10 BST"
},
"disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
"bpi": {
"USD": {
"code": "USD",
"rate": "11,761.4920",
"description": "United States Dollar",
"rate_float": 11761.492
},
"BTC": {
"code": "BTC",
"rate": "1.0000",
"description": "Bitcoin",
"rate_float": 1
}
}
}
```

From above json file i wanted to extract "rate": "11,761.4920".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in this line:

```
const {rate} = data;
```

you are trying to extract `rate` property using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), but that property is nested inside two objects:

```
$ curl -s 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json' | jq '.'
{
  "time": {
    "updated": "Aug 8, 2020 13:09:00 UTC",
    "updatedISO": "2020-08-08T13:09:00+00:00",
    "updateduk": "Aug 8, 2020 at 14:09 BST"
  },
  "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
  "bpi": {
    "USD": {
      "code": "USD",
      "rate": "11,769.7729",          <------ here it is
      "description": "United States Dollar",
      "rate_float": 11769.7729
    },
    "BTC": {
      "code": "BTC",
      "rate": "1.0000",
      "description": "Bitcoin",
      "rate_float": 1
    }
  }
}
$
```

correct syntax is:

```
const { bpi: { USD: { rate } } } = data;
```

here working rewrite of the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <body>
  <h1>show me btc current rate</h1>
  <p>current btc rate: <span id="btc_rate"></span>°</p>
  <script>
    const api_url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json';
    async function getBTC()
    {
      const response = await fetch(api_url);
      const data = await response.json();
      const { bpi: { USD: { rate } } } = data;
      document.getElementById('btc_rate').textContent = rate;
    }
    getBTC();
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```